# Counting sort in descending order

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures, counting-sort

This is a bit of a dumb question, but I keep receiving indexing errors whenever I attempt to reverse my logic.

How do I reverse an ascending counting sort algorithm?

Here is my code, which is able to sort ascendingly:

```
def count_sort(arr: StaticArray) -> StaticArray:
    """
    TODO: Write this implementation
    """
    # The output array that will have sorted arr
    new_arr = StaticArray(arr.size())
    # The count array that will store count of individual characters
    count = StaticArray(1000)
    for zero in range(count.size()):
        count.set(zero, 0)
    # identify the minimum number in the array
    min_element = arr[0]
    ind = 1
    while ind <= arr.size() - 1:
        if arr[ind] < min_element:
            min_element = arr[ind]
        ind += 1

    for i in range(0, arr.size()):
        count[arr[i] - min_element] += 1
   
    for j in range(1, 1000):
        count[j] += count[j-1]
    
    i = arr.size() - 1

    while i >= 0:
        new_arr[count[arr[i] - min_element] - 1] = arr[i]
        count[arr[i] - min_element] -=  1
        i -= 1

    return new_arr
```

Comment: "but I keep receiving indexing errors whenever I attempt to reverse my logic." We can only tell you what's wrong with code that you actually show. It does no good to show us the working version, and then ask about something that didn't work and is only vaguely described.

Comment: Once sorted, why not simply reverse the whole thing?

Answer (score 1):

per  [Thomas Weller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/480982/thomas-weller)'s suugestion,

```
def count_sort(arr: StaticArray, directio: str) -> StaticArray:
.
.
.
if direction == 'Reverse':
    return new_arr[::-1]
return new_arr
```